# what's the ratio of atoms of these two isotopes?

Tags: stoichiometry

here is a question says
:
[image]

I know that atom's number is found by =  $6.022*10^{23} * mol$

but how this formula is used here is what i dont know

what's the $idea$ of this question?

Answer (score 1):

You need more information.  They probably expect you to look in a book and see that the atomic weight (which is a weighted average over all isotopes) of $\ce{Tl}$ is 204.383.  Now if x is the amount of $\ce{^203Tl}$ with atomic weight 202.97 and (1-x) is....

Does that get you started?

$$\ce{(x*202_{.}97) + ((1-x)*204_{.}97)~=~?}$$

Can you get to the answer from here?

Comment: could you write one more line?

Comment: I think i got it. The final answer is 2.51, right?

Comment: Set the above equation equal to 204.383 and solve for x, the fractional amount of the TL 203 isotope.  You'll find that x=29%.  So about 29% of the 203 isotope and (1-.29) or 71% of the 205 isotope.